# Why can't I press [ESC] a fourth time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This script asks a question when the '*esc*' key is pressed to later receive a response, if '*y*' is typed the script continues and therefore continues intercepting the mouse coordinates, when '*n*' is pressed the script stops and if a response different from the previous ones is written it indicates an error message.

The problem is that I can't press the '*esc*' key a fourth time, that is, suppose I capture the coordinates of the mouse for a minute and press '*esc*', it asks the question, I answer with '*y*' and again it continues capturing the coordinates, If this procedure is repeated two more times there is no problem, it is the fourth time, the script keeps capturing the mouse coordinates, it does not recognize that '*esc*' is being pressed, therefore it does not launch the question or stop.

What is the cause of this error? And how can you modify the code so that you can press 'esc' on indefinite occasions?

```
#coding=utf-8
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse

running = True

print('The script is capturing the coordinates of the cursor...')

def get_coords(x, y):
    if running:
        print("Now at: {}".format((x, y)))

def on_press(key):
    global running
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        running = False
        print('The script has stopped. Do you wish to continue? (y/n)')
        while True:
            answer = raw_input()
            if answer == 'y':
                running = True
                print('The script was successfully resumed...')
                break
            elif answer == 'n':
                running = False
                print('The script has finished...')
                return False
            else:
                print('Invalid answer. Please enter "y" to continue or "n" to end the script.')


with mouse.Listener(on_move=get_coords) as listen:
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as keyboard_listener:
        keyboard_listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on mouse and keyboard listeners in Python, but the `on_press` function looks wrong.

An `on_press` function is supposed to receive and act on a single keyboard event.  But what you are doing in the function is to use `raw_input` to grab *more* key strokes: a "line" according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).  So now you have two things fighting over who is going to see / consume the keyboard events.  And based on the evidence, it seems that at some point the ESC key events are being consumed by a `raw_input` call ... in an attempt to complete another "line".

One solution will be to get rid of the `raw_input` call and implement a more complicated state machine so that `on_press` gets delivered (and handles) all input keystrokes via the `key` argument; i.e. ESC, 'y' and 'n' ... and anything else.

---

And you should NOT be writing new code in Python 2.7.  [It was end-of-life on Jan 1st 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).  You won't get any security updates for Python 2.7 now ... unless you **pay for** extended support from a commercial company.

---

Note that `raw_input` is renamed to `input` in Python 3.  But making that change does not solve your problem.